# Where to find NHibernate Jet driver

Tags: nhibernate, driver, jet

I don't know if it's just me, but I just can't seem to find the NHibernate Jet driver anywhere.

I have not yet looked into the source, but looking at the main project files or the NH Contrib files, did not give me any results.

Enough time wasted, who can show me the way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in NH Contrib, you must have missed it.  It's called NHibernate.JetDriver

Answer (score 2):

You can find more information about configuring NHibernate to work with MS Access in this post from my blog: [NHibernate and MS Access - it's simple, but...](http://dixond.blogspot.com/2010/08/nhibernate-and-ms-access-its-simple-but.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [Jet Driver on NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.JetDriver/) now:

```
PM> Install-Package NHibernate.JetDriver
```

It seems to work out the versions automatically.

Answer (score 0):

here is the svn url, you can check out the entire source and compile the newest dll
https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.JetDriver